# Multiple alarms are getting fired after reboot in android through broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-alarms

I am making a notification application and for that i am using scheduled alarms for running the notifications using Broadcast receiver class and i am prompting user to select from daily or hourly notifications and i am defining both alarms in the same receiver under the same function and it is working fine but the problems comes when i restart my device,when i restart it both the alarms (daily and hourly) are getting triggered when i am only setting one for example if i set an alarm for 11:20 A.M and restart my device the hourly one and this 11:20 one both are getting triggered,i want that when i restart my device only the alarm which was selected before the device boot only gets triggered.

My receiver class:-

```
public class alarmreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    int id=0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        start(context,id);

    }
    static void start(Context context,int id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, notification_receiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (id==1) {

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 9);
            calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingintent);
        }
            else

            if (id==2) {

                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60 * 1000
                        , pendingintent);
            }
        }
```

I am calling this function under button click listener like this:-
For daily notifications:-

```
alarmreceiver.start(getApplicationContext(),1);
```

For hourly notifications:-

```
alarmreceiver.start(getApplicationContext(),2);
```

Comment: Post the code that gets run when the device boots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60 * 1000, pendingintent);
```

sets a repeating alarm that goes off every minute, not every hour!

Also, this code sets an alarm that goes off right now and again every minute. The second argument to `setRepeating()` is the time of first alarm. You've passed `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` which basically means "now".

Comment: Thanks for you reply but your this doesnt answer my question my main problem is that when i am callling the function in onreceive function it is not accepting the value of alarm id when my device restarts.So when i restart my device my alarms are not triggering but if i dont restart my device they are working fine because they are using the function calling from the main activity.

Comment: You are calling `start()` from `onReceive()` but `id` has a value of `0`.

Comment: Yes i changed it i was just trying to check if it is even taking any value or not but its not working if i leave id null.

Comment: When i assign 1 or 2 to id in my broadcast receiver it is working after restart but i need that it should update the id in broadcast receiver from main activity and keep it assigned even if i restart my device.So user can choose between multiple alarms.

Comment: Is there any way to do this using putextra and getextra ?So i can update my id in receiver class function calling from the main activity.

Comment: I tried to do this with assigning nothing to the id in my reveiver class but when i restart my device its still taking id as null in my function call in my OnReceive method.

Comment: If you need to persist something across device reboots, then you will need to store it in `SharedPreferences` or a database or a file on the device. Nothing that you put in a `PendingIntent` or an alarm is persisted across reboots.

Comment: How can i apply SharePreference to do this can you please help me with it ?I mean how do i store that id in main activity using SharedPreference and use it in my receiver class after the device boots?

Comment: Just find a `SharedPreferences` tutorial like this one: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm `SharedPreferences` is just a way to store name/value pairs. Store your ID in there and read it when you need it.

Comment: Ok i will try to use SharedPreference for doing this and then i will report back to you if i'll get into any errors, thanks for your help,i'll just leave a comment on this post if i'll need any furthur help.

Comment: I did it using SharedPreference, i can't thank you enough for suggesting me to use SharedPreference and for helping me.I wish i could +rep your answer because i need 15 Rep for it which i don't have but thanks alot man.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance and welcome to the Stackoverflow community! In any case you can "accept" my answer by clicking on the green checkmark. You don't need any reputation points for that.